# How do I stop a 'white' page refresh in a multi page electron app

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, electron

I am just checking out electron - and like the idea of using it for a native app.

I am using bootstrap, and want each 'view' to be contained in a different file to another. I have got this working using the following example :

```
<div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">example</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="config_editor.html">Config editor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"> Status</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
```

note the  2 `<li>` links, one for index.html and one for config_editor.html

This is working - but the screen goes white when you click on a link, before loading in the next page - which breaks the immersion of a desktop ‘application’. How can this loading be sped up? Is there a different method for achieving this desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background color of the browser window to the same color as your pages:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'ElectronApp',
    backgroundColor: '#002b36',
});
```